# Using SED to Search and Replace Text in an XML file

Tags: xml, sed

I am using the SSED command line tool in Windows to perform a global search and replace on text in an XML file (this XML file is actually an export of a Task Manager Task).  When I look at the file before modifying it shows fine in notepad as text.  However after the search and replace is complete when I view the file many characters have been changed to unreadable text (special characters).

Anyone experienced this and know a way to ensure it remains as a text file?

Comment: You have to provide the sed command you used as well as a sample input file which cause this problem

Answer (score 0):

Doing this editing with a sed(1) script is going to be fragile and may break easily if the output or formatting of the XML changes.

Instead, look into xmlstarlet http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/ for a similar tool that works with XML files.  It's likely already in your distro, but might not be installed yet.